# What's the interest of using an ESB if data transported is never shared?

Tags: java, performance, web-services, esb

Some vendor wants to sell us the idea of using an esb for some big file we need to transfer to another server from a user. What's interest to make that data travel on the pipeline while it will never be used for any other app and in fact really retrieved once stored ? It will lower performance especially when files are big hundreds of mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not given much information on which to go on here.  What are your options for accessing the user's file?  Is it available via ssh/scp, HTTP GET (pull from user), or will it be uploaded via HTTP PUT/POST (push from user)?  Other?

What's your target?  How will you push the file to the target? [similar set of questions].

How is this to fit into your APIs/Web Interface?  How will you or your client/users interact with the interface to effect the file transfer?  It it to be "automated" on a timer?  Polling?

If you need flexibility now or in the future to the answers to these question, and/or you see any potential growth in the sources, targets, routing, additional file(s), other types of data, etc [i.e. you have "lots of stuff to manage"] - then consider the ESB.  The value in the ESB is (should be!) to abstract sources, targets, transports/protocols, and/or scheduling for automated transfers.

So in the absence of details, it's so very easy to suggest an ESB.  Apache ServiceMix is open software if you're open to that.

The down-side is deployment and configuration of the ESB, Sooo.... to automate copying from A to B for a one-shot deal on one platform in an ad-hoc environment, it's not necessarily "bad" to just write a script and schedule a cron job [you do document your deployment environment, right?] and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Since (some) ESB have ftp connectors/functionality, transfering such big file is not big performance flaw (except network). In fact depending on your system/business requirements using ESB to do thins job MAY be a good idea.